# Cloning parts of the document in other locations

Tags: input

I am correcting an article I wrote based on the reviews of my referees. What I want to do is to create a document that unifies both the text of the article (written in tex) and the corrections. Since in the corrections I need to quote verbatim parts of the article, I wondered if there is a smart way to do it.
If I had full control of the document (which I don't, since the document is shared with collaborators) I would put the sections I modified in a separate .tex file and include them in the text and in the corrections where I need to show what I modified as a standalone comment. In this way, I can modify the .tex file of the section every time I want and both the article and the corrections would be updated.
However, this is not possible, so I was wondering if there is a way to enclose some part of the text in some environment or just to call it with a label and then refer to the label/environment and clone the entire section to another place of the document. Something similar to the \snippet tool of Doxygen to be clear.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
 
\begin{document} 

% Part one: corrections
Here I review what I did in the in the first part and I quote [snippet_one]

Here I review the second part of the text and I quote [snippet_two]
% Part two: Full article

 [snippet_one]
Some text with also formulas
 [snippet_one]
Text text 
Some more text
 [snippet_two]
Some other text with other formulas
 [snippet_two]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could put everything you wanted to clone inside a `\newcommand{\someselection}{...}`, then call it  immediately afterwards in the body, and then again in the comments, but that's not a very elegant solution, so maybe someone else has a better idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the [`scontents` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scontents) for this. Enclose the part that you want to be able to repeat inside a `scontents` environment, and then recall it with `\getstored`.

```
\begin{scontents}[store-env=a_name]
text that you want to repeat
\end{scontents}

\getstored{a_name}
```

`a_name` is a name of your choice.

Comment: +1: Never heard of the `scontents` package, seems useful!

Comment: I found out about `scontents` a couple of years ago when I was looking for a way to create single exercise files that would contain, on one page, only the questions and, on another page, the questions and the answers. It's very robust, and I combine it with a small macro that reset counters, so that figure numbering is identical in both versions of the questions.

Comment: This worked almost perfectly, thanks! The only flaw I'm finding is that I can to call ```\getstored{a_name}``` only after I defined ```a_env``` and while not crucial, it's a pity. I hope there is an easy fix, but ```scontents``` just entered my list of packages to stay. (Also, you gave me a good tip for exercises sheets)